# Map empty Columns with CSVHelper

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I am using CSVHelper and I have the following MAP:

```
public class UserModelCsvMapper : CsvClassMap<UserModel> {
  public override void CreateMap() {
    Map(x => x.Name).Name("Name");
    Map(x => x.Email).Name("Email");
    Map(x => x.Linked).Name("Linked");
  } // CreateMap
} // UserModelCsvMapper
```

I would like to have more 2 columns on my CSV:

```
Country > UK (Always UK)

Code > "" (Always an empty string)
```

Is this possible?

Thank You

Comment: The last post on this thread may be helpful. https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/issues/209

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Constant value to always default the value of a field when reading and writing.

```
    Map(x => x.Country).Name("Country").Constant("UK");
    Map(x => x.Code).Name("Code").Constant("");
```

Documentation: https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/configuration/class-maps/constant-value

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see you generally can't, indeed (and this is an old post) the author suggests [here](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/issues/209#issuecomment-30008106) creating a fixed property in your class. That's probably the best solution; expand (either through inheritance or by directly adding extra properties) your class and populate with fixed values.

There is another option, which may work in specific cases and that's using `Map()` (see [here](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/api/CsvHelper.Configuration/ClassMap/) ), this would allow you do something like `Map().Name("Code")` however, as best as I can tell these while these fields appear in the order declared the values are being shifted, In your example this would be OK but if you declared Code first it would be populated with the value of Name in the generated .csv (I did try using  `Map().Name("Code").Index(0)` but to no avail). And I can't see a way to map a fixed value (doing something like `Map(m => "UK").Name("Country")` generates an error).

Answer (score -3):

If I understood your question correctly, your class should look like this:

```
public class UserModelCsvMapper : CsvClassMap<UserModel> {
  public override void CreateMap() {
    Map(x => x.Name).Name("Name");
    Map(x => x.Email).Name("Email");
    Map(x => x.Linked).Name("Linked");
    Map(x => "UK").Name("Country");
    Map(x => "").Name("Code");
  } // CreateMap
} // UserModelCsvMapper
```

Comment: I guess, that was the OP's intention, but such code gives `CsvHelper.Configuration.CsvConfigurationException: 'Empty' is not a property. Did you try to map a field by accident?`